# Динамическая ссылка в приложении Meet для Андройд

Tags: android

Вопрос в общем такой: создал приложение для Андройда ["Видеоконференция - бесплатная видеосвязь"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.confirec)
Между собой всё работает отлично, обмениваемся ссылкой и попадаем в нужную нам комнату, обмен производится динамической ссылкой.

```
 private fun handleDynamicLink() {
    Firebase.dynamicLinks
            .getDynamicLink(intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
                // Получить ссылку с результатом (может иметь значение NULL, если не найдено никакой связи)
                val deepLink: Uri?
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link
                    deepLink?.getQueryParameter("meetingCode")?.let { joinMeeting(it) }

                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { _ ->
                toast(getString(R.string.main_error_fetch_dynamic_link))
            }
}
```

Как видно, за попадание в комнату отвечает ключ "meetingCode" и код который каждый раз генерируется новый.
Всё работает супер. Но решил расширить возможности и создал сайт [Видеоконференция](https://videotranslation.ru) в котором динамическая ссылка открывается с этим ключом и не попадает в нужную комнату
https://videotranslation.ru/?rCounter=erersthh

Помогите убрать ?rCounter= из сылки, что бы работало коректно должно выглядеть так
https://videotranslation.ru/erersthh

Если из строкового ресурса

> https://videotranslation.ru/?meetingCode=%1$s

Убрать ?meetingCode= , то  работает обмен ссылкой с телефона на комп.
А вот обмен ссылкой телефон-телефон теряется.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то вам нужно из этого:

```
https://videotranslation.ru/?rCounter=erersthh
```

сделать это:

```
https://videotranslation.ru/erersthh
```

Есть два варианта: слепить свой урл или вырезать из строки ненужные буквы. Для вырезки букв можно воспользоваться описанном в [документации](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-range.html) методе :

```
fun CharSequence.removeRange(
startIndex: Int,
endIndex: Int
 ): CharSequence
```

где в качестве стартового индекса вы подаете такой:

```
url.indexOf("?")
```

а в качестве конечного индекса:

```
url.indexOf("=")
```

и на выходе получаете то что вам нужно. Второй вариант - построить свой урл немного сложнее и замороченнее, так как вам нужно будет вытащить `erersthh` из стартового урла предварительно. Для вытаскивания можем воспользоваться [методом из документации](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring.html):

```
fun String.substring(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): String
```

где в качестве стартового и конечного индекса используйте упомянутые выше индексы. Дальше строим урл вручную (пример ):

```
https://www.myawesomesite.com/turtles/types?type=1&sort=relevance#section-name
```

и строим:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("https")
    .authority("www.myawesomesite.com")
    .appendPath("turtles")
    .appendPath("types")
    .appendQueryParameter("type", "1")
    .appendQueryParameter("sort", "relevance")
    .fragment("section-name");
String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

какой вариант вам будет удобнее решать вам :)